# Matrix reduction trigonalisaton

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, translation-request

> Let 
>   $
>   \mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 
>     2 & -1 & -1  \\ 
>     2 & 1 &  -2\\
>     3 & -1 & -2
>   \end{bmatrix}
>    $
>
> - Trigonalise a matrix

in process of trigonalisation of matrix in question they choose $AC_3=C_3+C_2$ I'm wondering why exactly and what is algorithm behind that?

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are finding the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the matrix $A$.

They need to find three linearly independent eigenvectors for the three eigenvalues.

Due to the repeated eigenvalue, they need to find a [*Generalized Eigenvector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) for  $\lambda = 1$ due to the [*geometric and algebriac multiplicity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicities).

This can be written as $(A- \lambda I)C_3 = (A-I)C_3 = C_2$, hence $AC_3 = C_3 + C_2$.

$P$ is comprised of the three linearly independent eigenvectors as column vectors that correspond to each of the eigenvalues, that is:

$$P = ( C_1 ~~ C_2 ~~ C_3 )$$

You can see examples at:

- [Finding the Jordan canonical form of this upper triangule $3\times3$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226642/finding-the-jordan-canonical-form-of-this-upper-triangule-3-times3-matrix/226647#226647)
- [*Triple Root*](http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/jordan_form_3x3_triple_root)
- Many others on Math Stack Exchange

**Update**

It appears that the author meant "make triangular by similarity transformations", for example:

$$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  \lambda_{1} & a & b \\  0 & \lambda_{2} & c \\  0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

In this case, you can (in this order):

- $1.)~$ Try to diagonalize the matrix, which meets the definition. If that fails,
- $2.)~$ Find the Jordan Normal Form as I describe above and the author shows.

Comment: i think the question was trigonalisation and they said that A can be semblable of trigonalisation matrix and to achieve that they chooce the best form of matrix is jordan form because it's by default trigonalisation and then they can choose $C_{k}$ such that $AC_k=C_k+C_{k-1}$ due to the form of jordan contian the 1 up of its diagonal am i right ?

Comment: yes does mean similar

Comment: i will ask question about trigonalisation and let me see your way of how to trigonalise

Comment: could you add some names of good books in english wich treat this as details example or some web site homeroke with solution

Comment: please if you find my questions useful, Please recall to upvote and/or indicate that are intersting .

Comment: Wow, to trigonilize the matrix means to diagonalize it? I am very surprised this answer was accepted.

Comment: If you read the comments, the OP mistook the French meaning (and made me believe it), but that has been cleared up, it actually meant a similarity transformation and the answer is correct.