# Trigonalise a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 
>     0 & 1 & 1  \\ 
>    -1 & 1 & 1  \\
>    -1 & 1 & 2
>   \end{bmatrix}$
>
> - Trigonalise a matrix

Could someone trigonalise this matrix in details way, i wanna see the difference between yours and the french one

to start here's  $P_{1}(\lambda)=(\lambda -1)^3$

note that some authors in book's frnech use :

$$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  \lambda_{1} & 1 & 0 \\  0 & \lambda_{2} & 1 \\  0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

and other use $$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  \lambda_{1} & a & b \\  0 & \lambda_{2} & c \\  0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

im wondering wich way that you using in usa english's books

Comment: Is the matrix $A$ written correctly?

Comment: sorry it was typo i fixed it

Comment: You asked a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083430/matrix-reduction-trigonalisaton)....

Comment: nope it's note the first one was about tha way followed by the author of exercise and this one is direct question

Comment: there are others books in french didn't use this kind of trigonalisation they use $T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  \lambda_{1} & a & b \\  0 & \lambda_{2} & c \\  0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\ \end{array} \right)$

Comment: yes its match what they did for that books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @Ian's comment below, the author appears to be saying to "make triangular by similarity transformations", which gives something of the form (or like you added to the comment).

$$T = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  \lambda_{1} & a & b \\  0 & \lambda_{2} & c \\  0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\ \end{array} \right)$$

We try two things: $1.)~$ Diagonalize when possible, and if that fails, $2.)~$ Find the Jordan Normal Form.

For this specific problem, we have:

$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 1  \\ 
   -1 & 1 & 1  \\
   -1 & 1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}$$

We find the characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues using $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, resulting in:

$$-\lambda ^3+3 \lambda ^2-3 \lambda +1 = 0 \implies -(-1 + \lambda)^3 = 0 \implies \lambda_{1, 2, 3} = 1$$

Next, we want to find three linearly independent eigenvectors using $[A- \lambda I]v_i = 0$, but this is not always possible due to algebraic and geometric difference (deficient matrices), so we have to resort to [*generalized eigenvectors*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).

So, we have $[A - \lambda_1 I]v_1 = [A -I]v_1 = 0$ as:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0$$

If we put that in row-reduced-echelon-form (RREF), we arrive at:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) v_1 = 0$$

This only provides one linearly independent eigenvector as:

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, we need to find two more generalized eigenvectors and there are many approaches to that. One approach is to try $[A - \lambda I]v_2 = v_1$, yielding an augmented RREF of:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This yields $a = c, b = 1$, so choose $c = 0$, thus:

$$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Repeating this process, we set up and solve $[A - I]v_3 = v_2$, yielding an augmented RREF of:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This yields $a = -1 + c, b = -1$, so choose $c = 0$, thus:

$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

We can now form $P = (v_1~|~v_2~|~v_3)$ as:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This yields the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form):

$$T = PAP^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  1 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Note: there are various ways to solve these problems.

- You want to look for references with the Jordan Normal Form.
- You can sometimes infer $T$ (see references below).

Some sources for generalized eigenvectors and the Jordan Normal Form are:

- [*Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)
- [*Notes 1*](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jlindquist/115B/JCF.pdf)
- [*Notes 2*](http://www.math.utah.edu/~yplee/teaching/2270f14/Jordan_Form.pdf)
- [*Jordan Normal Form and Chaining*](http://math.postech.ac.kr/~sungpyo/LinearAlge-2007/Chap8.pdf)
- Book - Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote
- Books - many books on linear algebra

Comment: I think "trigonalize" means "make triangular by similarity transformations", not "make tridiagonal by similarity transformations".

Comment: @Ian: that would make much more sense! I cannot read French, so thanks for that clarification! I cleaned up the answer to remove the tridiagonal stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian Thanks Ian to clarification

Comment: @Amzoti  Thanks for detailed answer and for the references in english